# EF classes containing collections: Lists induce to use memory when navigating

Tags: entity-framework

When one wants to use EF navigation (navigating by the property of the classes), `List<T>`´s are all treated in memory.

For example I have this EF model class:

```
class School
{
    public virtual ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
    ...

    public School()
    {
         this.Courses = new List<Group>();  // List<T>!!
    }
}
```

And if I do this:

```
someSchool.Groups.Count
```

I will be counting the groups in memory and not in SQL (ie: these won't be counted like `"select count(*) from Groups join School Where SchoolId = ..."`)

So my question is.. **what should I use instead of List?**
IEnumerable is an interface so I can't have a new IEnumerable,... IQueryable too..

If no collection class is suitable for this, then I guess I should be using my DbContext instance. Like this:

```
(new MyDbContext()).Groups.Count(g => g.SchoolId == ...)
```

If that is the case, then: why is there EF navigation?!??

**Edit:**
Ok maybe I should use real information:

1. I'm already using ICollection (i used IEnumerable in the post because I thought they where similar)
2. This is the slow query: `domain.Persons.Count(p => p.IsStudent && p.GuardianId != null && p.Guardian.Mobile.Equals(""))`
3. This is the fast query: `db.Persons.Count(p => p.Domains.Any(d => d.DomainId == domain.DomainId) && p.IsStudent && p.GuardianId != null && p.Guardian.Mobile.Equals(""))`

As you can see, 2 and 3 are very similar ...one uses navigation and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ICollection<T>` instead and define your properties as virtual, so that you can lazy load and get your Count().

```
// Example
public virtual ICollection<Apple> Apples{get;set;}
```

`virtual` keyword enables EF to override its behavior and lazy load entities for you when you access the getter.

Comment: Sorry in the main post I typed IEnumerable but I have already tried ICollection and it does it in memory. Maybe my fault is in other place If what you say is true

Comment: Did you define it as 'virtual' also?

Comment: Maybe your entity configuration is not correct. Make sure you correctly mapped navigation properties and lazy loading is enabled in your context.

Comment: "lazy loading is enabled in your context", isn't by default?

Comment: Yes, it is default if you have not explicitly disabled.

Comment: Then that is not the problem. Maybe the "domain" variable (for which I use domain.Persons) is being treated in memory because it is passed through ViewBag?